# Why, in a car taking a sloped curve, friction is perpendicular to the car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

In solving the problem we usually use the friction as the centripetal force, but I could never understood how is this possible. I understand that if a car is making a circular motion, some centripetal force must be acting, and by discard we choose it to be the friction. But,is there some intuitive way to reason why friction must act perpendicular to the tires in this example?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a properly banked curve to remove the need for *any* radial friction to maintain the curve?

Comment: @User58220 yes, but it has a maximum speed that the car can have without skidding. If the spedd is large enough friction will also enter into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friction always oppose the natural tendency of the object to move in a given direction. In this case, if the car enters a frictionless sloped curve with a hight enough speed,  the tendency will be to go up the slope becaue it ir trying to go straight but as the slope is curved, it will end up going up (in addition to straight). Now, if you add friction, this one will oposse the upward tendency of the car, that is why the direction should be down the slope.